# Connecting PS3 and PC to one gateway

Tags: router, ethernet, ps3

I have a VersaLink 7500 Gateway with multiple ethernet ports. Can I simply connect both my PC and PS3 using seperate ethernet cables or can this cause damage to the gateway? I've been having trouble streaming Netflix on my PS3 connected wirelessly so I thought it might improve if it was wired.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, No†, It will‡.

† Assuming you use a proper Ethernet cable.
‡ Usually, but it depends on what speeds the devices & cables support and what nearby devices might be causing interference / contention.

Answer (score 1):

The four Ethernet ports are part of a switch, so it should be safe to connect to all of them. The device needs to be in router mode though, not bridge mode (I have no idea if this is relevant for this particular device.